# Drag multiple objects with InteractJS

Tags: javascript

I have a container with several objects and using InteractJS for drag&resize. Now I need to move multiple selected objects at the same time. Looks like `https://interactjs.io/docs/reflow` allows to run the action sequence but I can't make it work. I cannot just manually set the position of main object I drag because objects can be moved only inside the container and since this calculation is done by Interact internally I would like use its flow.

I have a small playground here https://jsfiddle.net/s1fapto9/2/

Does anyone have such experience with Interact?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to just move objects via cycle.

1. Get current object coordinates from HTML elements `.dataset`;
2. Get moving delta from `event.delta`;
3. Add delta to its prev coordinates.

   event => {
   widgets.forEach(el => {
   if(!el.getAttribute('selected')) {
   return;
   }
   const { x: dataX = '0', y: dataY = '0' } = el.dataset;

   ```
          const x = (parseFloat(dataX) || 0) + event.delta.x;
          const y = (parseFloat(dataY) || 0) + event.delta.y;


          el.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
          Object.assign(el.dataset, { x, y });
        });
      }
   ```

Edited example: https://jsfiddle.net/flashTGC/sfvu14q3/

Comment: your jsfiddle not working